# Amazon AWS upload-server-certificate format

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-iam

I have a website hosted on Amazon elasticbeanstalk and now I need to configure it for https and SSL. I have completed the first step from the link below "Create a custom domain with your DNS provider":

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

So now my amazon elasticbeanstalk site, example.elasticbeanstalk.com has custom domain example.com (I used Amazon Route 53 for this).

I am now performing step 2 from link above and following instructions given at the following link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html

I have created privatekey.pem and server.crt which I need to upload to Amazon IAM. I need help in typing the format for the following command to upload to IAM. My privatekey.pem and server.crt are located at Users/Kash on my MAC

> aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name
>   CertificateName --certificate-body file://public_key_certificate_file
>   --private-key  file://privatekey.pem

I typed the following but get error "keywords must be strings"

> aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name "TestCert"
>   --certificate-body file://server.crt --private-key file://privatekey.pem

I am not familiar with typing commands on terminal and need help

Answer (score 4):

The error is referring to the quotation marks at your "TestCert" certificate name.  There should be no quotation marks, as follows:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name TestCert --certificate-body file://server.crt --private-key file://privatekey.pem
```

Hope this helps!